# Equivalent of ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream in C#

Tags: java, c#, sockets, stream

What is the equivalent of theses Java classes in CSharp ?

It is for implement an interface with a socket.

Thanks

Comment: And the equivalent of the methods "getOutputStream()" and "getInputStream()" for a Socket ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many serializer available on .NET.

The simplest one is binary serialization. It is the most similar equivalent in C#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.110).aspx

The problem with that is that if you use this, your server and client will need to upgrade in lock steps (i.e. if you upgrade your server, you have to update all your clients, or the server wouldn't be able to deserialize requests from old clients)

DataContractSerializer provides XML formatted message and have options that is designed for web services so that it can do some version tolerance.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

In particular, it allow missed property (for example, when server is upgraded to allow more knobs, but old clients are not sending them).

For your another question.
To obtain a stream from a Socket, just create a System.Net.Socket.NetworkStream object instance with the socket as an argument.

```
Stream s = new NetworkStream(socket);
```

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) abstract away a lot of details on programming distributed systems. It is much easier to program a server client application using WCF instead of messing with raw sockets.

Comment: Thanks!

And what is the equivalent of it " in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream())); " in order to write in a socket ?

Comment: It does not work that way in C#
You create a NetworkStream object instance, and then use a Serializer object to write to that stream.






It is more like






in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
in.writeObject(objectToWrite);






will translate to






NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(sock);
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(objectToWrite, ns);

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct equivalent of it, but it's functionality is very easily achieved using a plain Stream and XmlSerializer/BinaryFormatter.

Here is an example using XmlSerializer:

```
public void StoreToFile<T>(T ObjectToStore, string FileName)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using(Stream str = File.Create(FileName))
        ser.Serialize(str, ObjectToStore);
}

public T RetrieveFromFile(string FileName)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using(Stream str = File.Open(FileName))
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(str);
}
```

Then, when you want to store a class in a file use:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass(); //The class we want to store.
StoreToFile(instance, "instance.dat");
```

And to retrieve it:

```
MyClass instance = RetrieveFromFile<MyClass>("instance.dat");
```

This is a basic example storing just one class in a file, but you can extend it to store more items concatenated on these streams.

Also, the getOutputStream and getInputStream doesn't have a direct counterpart, you can always use a NetworkStream:

```
NetworkStream myStream = new NetworkStream(theSocket);
```

It will behave as an input and output stream, in .net streams usually are read/write, so no need to have two sepparated streams.

Answer (score 0):

The same can be done using JSON serialization, e.g.:

```
    private StreamReader inputStream = ...;
    private StreamWriter outputStream = ...;
            
     public void writeObject<T>(T s)
     {
          if (outputStream != null)
          { string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(s);
            outputStream.WriteLine(jsonString); 
          }
          else
          { Console.WriteLine("ERROR: null output stream!");  }
     }

        public T readObject<T>()
        { if (inputStream != null)
          {
            string jsonString = inputStream.ReadLine();
            T res =
              JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);
            return res;
          }
          return default(T); 
        }
```

Note that `T` must be a public class and only public fields are serialized.